Bash script to start/stop ComfyUI
I'm trying to create a bash script and .desktop shortcut that toggle (start and stop) the ComfyUI server. This is my current working bash script to start the ComfyUI server:
#!/bin/bash

# activate the venv
source ./AI/ComfyUI/venv/bin/activate

# start ComfyUI
python3 ./AI/ComfyUI/main.py

Taking some clues from this question, How do I check with a Bash script if an application is running?

how do I replace the bash input used in that script with a simple hard coded command to the python script? Is the below attempt correct?
since it's using venv is there anything extra I need to do when I check the instance and then kill it if it's there?


BASECMD=${1%%\ *}

#is this correct?
PID=$("python3 ./AI/ComfyUI/main.py" "$BASECMD")

if [ "$?" -eq "0" ]; then
   echo "at least one instance of "$BASECMD" found, killing all instances"

   # stop ComfyUI
   kill $PID
else
   echo "no running instances of "$BASECMD" found, starting one"

   # activate the venv
   source ./AI/ComfyUI/venv/bin/activate

   # start ComfyUI
   $1

fi

Last (minor) detail, for the .desktop shortcut I point to an icon. If possible I'd like to toggle icons for the start/stop states (like the image below). Is this possible with a .desktop?


This should work for you.  Just modify the path's to the appropriate locations.
#!/bin/bash

pid_file="/tmp/comfyui.pid"
script_pid=""

update_icon() {
    if [ -z "$script_pid" ]; then
        # Not running, use inactive icon
        sed -i 's|^Icon=.*|Icon=/path/to/icon-inactive.png|' ~/Desktop/comfyui.desktop
    else
        # Running, use active icon
        sed -i 's|^Icon=.*|Icon=/path/to/icon-active.png|' ~/Desktop/comfyui.desktop
    fi
}

source /absolute/path/to/AI/ComfyUI/venv/bin/activate

# Check if file exists and read the PID
if [ -f "$pid_file" ]; then
    script_pid=$(cat "$pid_file")
fi

# Check if the process is running
if [ -n "$script_pid" ] && kill -0 "$script_pid" 2>/dev/null; then
    kill "$script_pid"
    wait "$script_pid"
    rm "$pid_file"      # Remove the PID file
    script_pid=""       # Clear the PID
else
    # If not running, start ComfyUI
    python3 /absolute/path/to/AI/ComfyUI/main.py &
    script_pid=$!
    echo "$script_pid" > "$pid_file"  # Save the PID to a file
fi

update_icon

deactivate

exit 0

The ~/.local/share/applications/comfyui.desktop file:
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=ComfyUI
Exec=bash -c "/absolute/path/to/my_script.sh"
Icon=/path/to/icon-inactive.png
Type=Application
Terminal=false

Copy it to your Desktop so it can be visible and you can freely change the .desktop file without affecting the default one stored in ~/.local:
cp ~/.local/share/applications/comfyui.desktop ~/Desktop/comfyui.desktop


@JayCravens thank's for your answer but I'm confused about a detail here. The .desktop file is calling the python script /path/to/AI/ComfyUI/main.py, that should be the bash script you have included above, but then that bash script also calls the same python script - that can't be right. Surely the bash script is being missed out? I need it to be ComfyUI.desktop -> ComfyUI-bash.sh -> main.py (main.py is part of ComfyUI so shouldn't be modified).

@garrettlynchirl It's just about using absolute path's, as terdon pointed out.  I updated the scripts to reflect it.  You are correct, it should be the /path/to/my_script.sh on the .desktop file.

@garrettlynchirl I changed the icon update to use the existing variable to be more reliable.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
